# Python draw path between point

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

Supposing I have a np.array like that:

```
data = np.array([[1,2],[2,4],[3,5],[4,5]])
```

I want to plot the path from the first point to the second then from the second to the third etc...
How can I manage that. I know how to link all the point but not with a specifies order.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.array([[1,2],[2,4],[3,5],[4,5]])
plt.plot(data[:, 0], data[:, 1])
plt.show()
```

[image]

Alternatively, as suggested (this one by @fuglede is **really nice**):

```
plt.plot(*data.T)
```

Comment: Alternatively, `plt.plot(*data.T)`.

Comment: @fuglede Great! I like it

Comment: Is it possible to update actively and like show it as if we are playing a video?

Comment: You should use animation: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/animation_api.html If you search for it you will find a lot of tutorial on how to use it